# Automating shell press enter to continue

Tags: shell, puppet

I am trying to automate installation of some software, unfortunately the silent installer half way through pauses, you then have to restart the server in another window, and then press enter to continue.

Is there a way to automate a "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE"?

So there will be one process A which is kicked off first and it will then wait for PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.

When that happens process B will be launched, finish its work and then reset process A by "PRESSING ENTER"

I am using Puppet as the automation framework

Answer (score 0):

command-line automation, Expect is the classic tool. Or try pexpect if you're more comfortable with Python.

if that doesn't sound feasible, make your `shell script` dynamic to support silent installation i.e installation from the **response file**